# Regex: Extract everything after forward slash in Google Bigquery?

Tags: sql, regex, google-bigquery

I have two scenarios below. I would like to extract everything after `search/` or between `search/` and `category/`

Scenario 1, where I want everything after `search/`:

```
/listBuilder/20568284/search/1"X4"-8 t%26g
```

Scenario 2, where I want everything between `search/ and category/`:

```
listBuilder/20464071/search/decking screws/category/6765
```

**Edit & Further Clarity**

**Say I have a column with the following information**

```
Column1
/listBuilder/20568284/search/1"X4"-8 t%26g
listBuilder/20464071/search/decking screws/category/6765
```

**From column1 how can I get a new column, using regex, with the following ideal information**

```
Column2 
1"X4"-8 t%26g
decking screws
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider below

```
select text, 
  regexp_extract(text, r'search/(.+)') as after_search,
  regexp_extract(text, r'search/(.+)category/') as between_search_and_category,
from `project.dataset.table`
```

if you need to handle/extract into one column - consider below

```
select regexp_extract(text, r'search/(.+?)(?:/category|$)')  
from `project.dataset.table`
```

If applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much this should work, however both of these strings are in one column. Is there any logic that could do it in one line of code?

Comment: not sure what you mean - post new question with details and we will be happy to answer :o)

Comment: I may edit the current question because I am unsure how to rephrase the question properly without stack saying my question too similarly phrased as another question

Comment: updated the current question, thank you so much

Comment: Following your edit you can just replace the two regex_extract from @MikhailBerlyant answer into a combined regex_extract with regex_extract(text,  , r'search\/(.+)(?:category\/|$)')